# How is it possible for crypto exchanges teams to not be public?

Tags: exchanges

Sorry, I'm not sure if this directly relates to bitcoin or not. Will be glad to post it on another stack exchange if anybody has ideas behind which one would be better.

I was on coingecko checking out exchanges and I occasionally see that exchanges teams are "anonymous" but I'm wondering how is this possible?

To register the domain you need to provide some sort of personal information. Same with the hosting, you need to give hosting some sort of information...unless you host it yourself, but it's not really feasible to host an exchange off of your local machines unless you're a devOps master (anyway, maybe we can skip past this one).

Not to mention, how are you going to run this exchange? You need to hire a team, at the bare minimum customer support. Is it really possible to be this good at hiding your identity entirely?

Namely, the exchange in question is hitbtc.com

Comment: There are ways of registering domains anonymously. Web hosting businesses can exist in jurisdictions without any requirement that customers details be made public.

Comment: @RedGrittyBrick really, I didn't know that was possible. But even their team? Basically they have to hire team members all while staying anonymous. Seems like a crazy amount of work.